# MSCRM 2011 rollup and Language Pack Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a fresh installation of CRM 2011 on a box for  front end (: Win2008 R2) and another box for the database (SQL Server 2008 R2 on Win2008 R2 also)

I applied all windows updates to both OS till Dec,20th 2013

The installation of CRM went smoothly. My problem started when I tried to install the rollups.

Whatever roll up I try I get this error :

> MS Dynamics CRM English (United States) Language Pack is not installed on this computer.

I am sure I have CRM with English Language (1033).

And I tried to install this language pack again from the downloaded  install file and I get  :

> You cannot proceed with installation because the language of the language pack, English(US), you are trying to install is the same language as MS CRM Server

I even unistalled CRM completely and installed it again. Same error pops up.

Any ideas what could possibly cause this ?

Comment: I have 
- SQL 2008R (5.0.9690.3731 in Deplyment Manager with SRS Data Connector installed)
- CRM 2011 (v 5.0.9690.1992)

Comment: thanks marc_s for the corrections :)

Comment: In this case also I ended by fixing this by myself.

Basically, I installed a French Language pack then installed the Roll up 15.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case also I ended by fixing this by myself. Basically, I installed a French Language pack then installed the Roll up 15. Hope this helps somebody else.